# Indentation inside of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, nodes

I have nodes with text and I want them like in the first two nodes. As you can see the solution has its flaws: First I have to manually adjust the indent and so cannot be sure if it is correct aligned and second, once the text gets a little shorter/longer it stops to work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
        
        \usepackage{tikz}
        
        \begin{document}
            
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                
                \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,0) {\parindent=6.8em How are you?: Fine. \\ 
                    \indent Thanks};
                
                \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-2) {\parindent=6.8em How are you?: Fine. \\ 
                    \indent Thanks \\ Very fine!};
                
                \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-4) {\parindent=6.8em How are you today?: Fine. \\ 
                    \indent Thanks};
                
                \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-6) {\parindent=6.8em Fine?: Yes, Fine. \\ 
                    \indent Thanks \\ very fine actually};
                
                \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-8) {\parindent=6.8em Fine?:\indent Yes, Fine. \\ 
                    \indent Thanks \\ No, not fine};
                
                \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-10) {
                    \makebox[6.8em][l]{How are you?:} Fine. Thank you very much I really appreciate it
                };
                
            \end{tikzpicture}   
            
        \end{document}

    \end{tikzpicture}  
    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a better way to align text in nodes that way? Thanks.

EDIT: The text should not exceed the nodes border nor be centered. Therefore, the text should start at the top left corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may liked the following design of your nodes :-). By use of `description` defined in the `enumitem` package you can get the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tikzitem}{description}{1}  % <-- defined new list
\setlist[tikzitem]{nosep,
                   leftmargin=27mm,
                   style=nextline, 
                   before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip} 
                   }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains} % just for shorter code in MWE

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm,
      start chain = going below,
every node/.style = {draw, text width=56mm, align=left,
                     inner xsep=1mm, on chain}
                        ]
\node   {\begin{tikzitem}
        \item[How are you?] Fine.\par   
                            Thanks
        \end{tikzitem}};
\node   {\begin{tikzitem}
        \item[How are you?] Fine.\par   
                            Thanks\par   
                            Very fine!
        \end{tikzitem}};
\node   {\begin{tikzitem}
        \item[How are you today?] 
                            Fine.\par
                            Thanks
        \end{tikzitem}};
\node   {\begin{tikzitem}
        \item[Fine?]        Yes, Fine.\par
                            Thanks\par 
                            very fine actually
        \end{tikzitem}};
\node   {\begin{tikzitem}
        \item[Fine?]        Yes, Fine.\par
                            Thanks\par 
                            No, not fine
        \end{tikzitem}};
\node   {\begin{tikzitem}
        \item[How are you?] Fine. Thank you very much I really appreciate it
        \end{tikzitem}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

For shorter code you may define nrw command, for example `\Item`:

```
\newcommand\Item[2]{\begin{description}[nosep,
                                       leftmargin=27mm,
                                       style=nextline,
                                       before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
                                       ]
                    \item[#1] #2
                    \end{description}
                    }
```

and than use it node:

```
\node   {\Item{How are you?}{Fine.\par
                            Thanks}};
```

Comment: +1: Nice. Unusual combination, at least for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can put a `minipage` inside a TikZ's node. Therefore, you are free to use all TeX/LaTeX commands, in particular, indentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=yellow!30,inner sep=3mm]{
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
How are you? Fine!\\
\noindent\phantom{How are you?} Thank you!
\end{minipage}
};      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am definitely not an expert but I am happy to try to help (and good luck with the moderator election, I voted).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{Proposal}

% \makebox[width][position]{text}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,0) {
            \makebox[6.8em][l]{How are you?:} Fine. \\ 
            \makebox[6.8em][r]{} Thanks
            };
        
        \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-2) {
            \makebox[6.8em][l]{How are you?:} Fine. \\ 
            \makebox[6.8em][r]{} Thanks \\
            \makebox[6.8em][r]{} Very Fine! \\
            };
        
        \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-4) {
            \makebox[6.8em][l]{How are you today?:} Fine. \\ 
            \makebox[6.8em][r]{} Thanks
            };

    \end{tikzpicture}  
    
\section{Original}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,0) {\parindent=6.8em How are you?: Fine. \\ 
            \indent Thanks};
        
        \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-2) {\parindent=6.8em How are you?: Fine. \\ 
            \indent Thanks \\ Very fine!};
        
        \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-4) {\parindent=6.8em How are you today?: Fine. \\ 
            \indent Thanks};
        
        \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-6) {\parindent=6.8em Fine?: Yes, Fine. \\ 
            \indent Thanks \\ very fine actually};
        
        \node[text width=5.5cm,draw] at (0,-8) {\parindent=6.8em Fine?:\indent Yes, Fine. \\ 
            \indent Thanks \\ No, not fine};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    
\end{document}
```

[image]